Is every open substack of $Y$ of the form $[U/G]$ where $U$ is an open subscheme of $X$?
Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a scheme $X$. Consider the algebraic stack quotient $Y=[X/G]$:
Is every open substack of $Y$ of the form $[U/G]$ where $U$ is an open subscheme of $X$?

If $V \subset Y$ is an open substack then its preimage $U \subset X$ is an open subscheme (because $X \to Y$ is continuous). Moreover, since $X \to Y$ is a principal $G$-bundle, it follows that $U \to V$ is a principal $G$-bundle. Therefore, $V = [U/G]$.
